# Intellij Idea 12 Html 5 support?

Tags: html, intellij-idea

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        dialog{ display: block; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<dialog>
    <dt>Sam</dt>
    <dd>Knock, Knock.</dd>
    <dt>Eric</dt>
    <dd>Who's there?</dd>
    <dt>Sam</dt>
    <dd>Justin.</dd>
    <dt>Eric</dt>
    <dd>Justin who?</dd>
    <dt>Sam</dt>
    <dd>Justin time for dinner!</dd>
</dialog>
</body>
</html>
```

I believe this is perfectly fine for an HTML 5 file. However IntelliJ complaints about:

> dialog{ display: block; }

saying:

**Invalid CSS selector less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection detects inappropriate values assigned to CSS attributes. For example, invalid measurement units or values out of range.**

1) Is this not valid HTML5, and am I wrong?

2) If it is ok, then how to stop Intellij complaining about it?

IntelliJ thinks that I must apply style to a class or an id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<dialog>` tag is not a valid HTML5 tag.  It was dropped from the specification around September 2009.

Comment: Thank you. Did not know that. I did not even know HTML5 was tat old!

Comment: @jmoerdyk - http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-html5-20121217/interactive-elements.html#the-dialog-element - It's not the same `dialog` element, but it is a valid HTML element.